# What are the advantages of B plus tree over skip list?

Tags: database, data-structures

So recently I am learning database system on Youtube published by CMU. The professor said skip list is like the rotated B+ tree. And it seems that the time complexity of operations on b+ tree and skip list is nearly the same. Plus, skip list does not need to store intermediate nodes like B+ tree does. However, rare DBMS uses skip list to store indexes of tables. So what are the advantages of B+ tree over skip list?

Comment: Skip list does not self balance.... if your data never changes skip list is fine -- otherwise it is a poor choice.

Comment: Someone did a fairly detailed analysis [here](https://github.com/Jigar54/B-tree-v-s-Skip-Lists).  My understanding is that B+ trees are more amenable to the way disks are designed, i.e. sectors, tracks, etc., although solid state drives are rendering this advantage moot.  As Hogan pointed out, B+ trees are self-balancing, a really important property for databases.

Comment: Yeah, at the beginning I was thinking that skip list does not need to rebalance and I took it as an advantage. Anyway, thanks for both comments. Really helpful.